# How do I write MATLAB code for a DAC converter ?

Tags: matlab, digital-analog-converter

In the first step I generated a sequence of bits (0,1)..

I used a randi command `x = randi([0 1],1,3)` to generate random bits

I stuck with these 2 steps :

**Divide sequence by 3 bits into 8 levels
[000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111]**

**For each quantum level assigns amplitude value from the range [-2, 2]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't provide the full source code to leave a bit of the homework for you, but I will give you some hints:

- `randi()` is creating a sequence of 0 and 1 floating point numbers
- Look at the documentation of function `bitpack`. This allows you to pack your bits from array elements into a single byte. Be aware that you need to provide an 8 element array of "bits" to fill a byte. User 'uint8' as the class argument.
- before passing the array of floating point numbers to bitpack you have to convert it to a `logical` array by using the `logical()` function.
- look at the documentation of `linspace()` to create an array with 8 elements containing your equally spaces amplitude values
- lookup the amplitude value in this array for each "digital" value.